# Integral over a circular arc

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, vector-analysis, line-integrals

Let the vector field $\vec{F}$ be defined by $\vec{F}=y\mathbf{i}+x\mathbf{j}$ evaluate the path integral: $$\int \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}$$ Along that part of the circular path $x^2+y^2=1,z=0$ from $(1,0,0)$ to $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0\right)$ via the shortest route.
I know that the answer should be $\frac{1}{2}$ from my lecturers solutions but I can't seem to get it

My solution attempt :
$$\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}=\int_{(1,0,0)}^{ \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0\right)}ydx+xdy$$
Let $x=\cos(\theta)$ $y=\sin(\theta)$ then we have that $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$,$\theta=0$ so the integral becomes $$[yx+xy]^\frac{\pi}{4}_0=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta=1\ne \frac{1}{2}$$ Where is my mistake? I can't seem to see it, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do we know whether the value of the integral cares about which path you take on your path to the goal? If so then the notation start point end point in 3D may not make sense.

Comment: it says via the shortest route

Comment: Ah, ok. So then we need some way to measure distance. Or is it just the shortest path in the space? But it says circular arc?

Comment: the question says, evaluate the path intergral $\int \vec{F}.d\vec{r}$ along that part of the circular path $x^2+y^2=1$, $z=0$ from the point $(1,0,0)$ to $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0)$ via the shortest route.

Comment: Ah ok so the shortest way along the circle so you don't go the wrong rotation, sorry I may have read sloppily.

Comment: it is okay, the answer my lecturer got was $\frac{1}{2}$ but i don't understand how..

Comment: For some reason I keep getting 0. If $x=\cos\theta$ and $y=\sin\theta$ then $x\text{d}y+y\text{d}x=0$

Comment: $xdy+ydx$ $$=cos^2(\theta)d\theta-sin^2(\theta)d\theta$$

Comment: Neaouw.. the difference... more like a double angle is it not?

Comment: @Gibberish there's your mistake, $\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta=\cos2\theta$

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the field is obviously the gradient of the function $xy$ and the integral along any path from $(1,0,0)$ to $(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2},0)$ is the difference of the function values which is $1/2\,.$